# How to implement DRY programming with multiple menus in bash

Tags: bash, menu

I have selection menus in my bash script and I was curious if there was a way to simplify and condense the menus without repeating myself. I've tried many different methods to no avail, does anyone know of a good way to condense this code:

```
    PS3="some menu"
    options=("option1" "option2" "option3" "exit")
    select opt in "${options[@]}"
    do
        case $opt in
            "option1")
                something
                ;;
            "option2")
                something else
                ;;
            "option3")
                something different
                ;;
            "exit")

                ;;
            *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
        esac
        read -p "Press Enter to continue"
        clear
        return 1
    done

    PS3="some menu 2"
    options=("option 1" "option2" "exit")
    select opt in "${options[@]}"
    do
        case $opt in
            "option 1")
                something
                ;;
            "option 2")
                something
                ;;
            
            "exit")
                exit
                ;;
            *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
        esac
        read -p "Press Enter to continue"
        clear
        return 1
    done
```

I want to condense this code without repeating multiple menus in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a dispatch table, mapping the option text to the function for that option. This requires bash version 4.4+ for the use of `local -n` namerefs

```
fn_a1() { echo "do something here for option a1"; }
fn_a2() { echo "do something here for option a2"; }
fn_a3() { echo "do something here for option a3"; }
fn_b1() { echo "do something here for option b1"; }
fn_b2() { echo "do something here for option b2"; }

prompt() {
    local PS3="$1: "
    local -n _options=$2 _dispatch=$3
    select opt in "${_options[@]}"; do
        if [[ -v _dispatch["$opt"] ]]; then
            "${_dispatch[$opt]}"
            break
        fi
    done
}

declare -A dispatch_table
declare -a options

options=( "option a1" "option a2" "option a3" exit )
dispatch_table=(
    ["option a1"]=fn_a1
    ["option a2"]=fn_a2
    ["option a3"]=fn_a3
    ["exit"]=exit
)
prompt "some menu" options dispatch_table

options=( "option b1" "option b2" exit )
dispatch_table=(
    ["option b1"]=fn_b1
    ["option b2"]=fn_b2
    ["exit"]=exit
)
prompt "some menu 2" options dispatch_table
```

I send the options as a separate array so I can control the **order** of the menu: iterating over the keys of an associative array has no inherent order.

Comment: I get these errors when running this script ./test: line 9: local: warning: options: circular name reference 
./test: line 9: warning: options: circular name reference
./test: line 10: warning: options: circular name reference
./test: line 10: warning: options: circular name reference

Comment: right, you can use them as global variables. I forgot that you can't re-use the name -- bash's local variables are not in a truly local scope. I've renamed the variables in the function with a leading underscore.

Comment: What if options had a second condition for instance say I wanted to run a function and set a value to a variable like "something;var=1"

Comment: You would add that to the function

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a function and call it twice, something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

prompt() {
    local opt
    local -A isExpected
    local -a options
    PS3="$1"
    shift
    options=()
    for opt; do
        isExpected["$opt"]=1
        options+=("$opt")
    done
    isExpected["exit"]=1
    options+=("exit")
    select opt in "${options[@]}"
    do
        if (( "${isExpected[$opt]}" )); then
            case $opt in
                "option 1")
                    something
                    ;;
               "option 2")
                    something
                    ;;
                "option 3")
                    something
                    ;;
                "exit")
                    ;;
                *) printf 'invalid option "%s"\n' "$REPLY" >&2;;
            esac
        else
            printf 'unexpected option "%s"\n' "$opt" >&2
        fi
        read -r -p "Press Enter to continue"
        clear
        return 1
    done
}

prompt "some menu" "option 1" "option 2" "option 3"
prompt "some menu 2" "option 1" "option 2"
```

Obviously you can move all the common options into `prompt()` just like I did for `"exit"`. If the order of options presented doesn't matter then you can get rid of `isExpected[]` and just use the one associate array to hold `options` and access for select using `${!options[@]}"`.

Comment: What about more than 3 options ?

Comment: How would I change the options values (something) ?

Comment: Code however many options you like and whatever somethings you like. If there's something you need that's not covered by your question then update your question to clarify your requirements with a more truly representative example.